# Closing youtube standalone activity

Tags: android, eclipse, youtube, android-youtube-api

I made an app on android to view Youtube videos by using Standalone Player of Youtube (see [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer)).  Everything is okay but I cannot add a stopping activity for it. Is there any way of finishing this activity? Thanks.

```
private int REQ_PLAYER_CODE = 1;
private static String YT_KEY = "AIzaSyAHBXzpIsBAGhKZwjvI0LoXDfc8hCqw64I";
private static String VIDEO_ID = "sjOfxnlGAF4"; // Your video id here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.digersayfa);

    Intent videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, YT_KEY, VIDEO_ID, 0, true, false);

    startActivityForResult(videoIntent, REQ_PLAYER_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQ_PLAYER_CODE && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.getReturnedInitializationResult(data);
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, 0).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format("PLAYER ERROR!!", errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for me it is totally unclear - what exactly are you planning to do?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by stopping the activity? The YouTube activity should be added to the back stack so that when a user click the back button on the phone, the activity is exited.

I'm confused about the fact that you want to add functionality to another application...

Comment: actually when you start YouTubeStandalonePlayer intent and while video playing activity not getting close on back press for more info please check at your end.

Comment: @Prags Did u found the solution?